# Is cursor over element (on page load)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a .hover() action assigned to an element to hide/show something depending on the cursor being over it. The problem I am running into is that when the page loads and the cursor is OVER the element it doesn't register as being over because its not firing the mouseenter event.

Is there a another way to tell if the cursor is over a desired element?

Comment: The problem is there is no way that I know of (or that Google seems to know of) to get the mouse coordinates without the user moving the mouse. This may be a limitation you'll need to live with or work-around.

Comment: I guess I was coming here for help with the work around.

Comment: When I say you'll need to work around it, I don't mean you need to implement a work-around (from what I can see there isn't a very good one). I meant you would have to work around it as far as your design and interactions.

Comment: If this is important to you, put the cursor somewhere defined on load. set the focus somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the mouse position on page load you could call

```
var currentElement = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
```

then if the element found at that position is the one with the hover event.  You can trigger that hover event manually

```
$(currentElement).trigger('hover');
```

Comment: The problem with this is - how do you get the mouse position on page load, without moving the mouse? Every example I've seen online shows to use the `mousemove` handler.

Comment: I dont believe you can...you could check the onload event and see if it actually provides mouse x and y coordinates but I believe it wont.  you must wait for the mouse to move slightly before this will work.

Comment: onload provides no such event data.

Answer (score 1):

If you hide the element(s) until the page is done loading and then show them all at once, will your mouseover event now fire?

```
<div id='allmyelementsinhere' style='display:none'>
```

then use javascript to remove the display:none on page load.

I'm thinking that your mouseevent will fire as soon as you display the elements.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue with next and previous navigation buttons that navigate between consistently designed pages.

A user would click next to go to the next page, and because their mouse was in the same position on the page load of the second page, they were able to click next again to continue navigating through the collection of pages. Essentially a convenient next/previous UI.

Except of course that the hover state didn't display on page load for the second and subsequent pages.

So I added a url parameter (action='next or action=prev) and then on load I put the next or previous button into the hover state if the relevant url parameter is present. If the user has somehow moved their mouse and isn't over the button then you do get a button incorrectly in it's hover state until the first mousemove event.

It's not perfect and it only suits this specific circumstance where a user is using a consistent UI within pages on your site, but as this sort of UI is a fairly common - especially in blogs/galleries I though I'd mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the jquery method to track mouse position starting from page load.

```
(function($) {
  $.mousePos = {x: 0, y: 0};
  var recordPos = function(e) {
    $.mousePos.x = e.pageX;
    $.mousePos.y = e.pageY;
  };
  $(document).mousemove(recordPos).mouseover(recordPos);
})(jQuery);
```

This will populate **$.mousePos.x** and **$.mousePos.y** as soon as the mouse **starts to interact** with the page.

Answer (score -2):

[Script to get mouse coordinates on load](http://javascript.internet.com/page-details/mouse-coordinates.html)

Comment: This is the same problem. Load that page and don't move your mouse. The values stay at zero (at least for me). The key is the line `document.onmousemove = getMouseXY;`

Comment: How exactly is that on load? Keep your mouse in place and the boxes show 0 and 0.

Comment: I tested in chrome and IE8, and for both without moving my mouse it worked.

Comment: In fairness this seems to work in IE8 & FF - but in chrome there is a 5 second delay, which is why I didn't see it the first time. Sort of defeats the purpose.

Comment: I guess the key line I missed was `if (!IE) document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE)`